# regex match hyphen in string

Tags: regex

I have a regex `\([0-9]+|\-)\` which either takes a number or a hyphen.

but if I use this to match something like `-555` it still works because it matches the hyphen`-`. So I am wondering if there is a way to match the whole thing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
/^([0-9]+|\-)$/
```

The `^` means "at the beginning of the <strike>string</strike> line", and the `$` means "at its end".

**Edit:** fixed the answer, thanks to luke-gru. As pointed out in the comments, `\A` is at the start of the string, `\Z` is at its end. The behavior of `^` and `$` depends on whether multiline is enabled or not.

Comment: Just to be a dirty pedant, \A and \Z are beg. and end of string, while ^ and $ are beg. and end of line. Most of the time they're the same, but hitting the outlier sucks when you're not prepared for it.